# Remove iOS version without uploading build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have a issue with my versioning of app. I have created version **1.4.4.1** on iTunes Connect, but I cannot upload any binary for this version from XCode

*ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString '1.4.4.1' in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers."*

So how can I upload the binary even if I want to change the version to 1.4.5 I am unable to remove 1.4.4.1 from iTunes Connect and for making it **Developer Reject** it requires you to first submit for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to ItunesConnect
2. Select the new version you created `1.4.4.1`
3. Scroll to `General App Information`. Just below Icon you can change the version no from `1.4.4.1` to `1.4.5`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Bilal